# What does ":exists" do on a route template?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I read an article which discusses how to setup a custom path for a view.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/expanding-razor-view-location-and-sub-areas-in-asp-net-core/

Routing code setup was not clear.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "subAreaRoute",
        template: "{area:exists}/{subarea:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

What does this do: `{area:exists}`? What is it checking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`exists` applies `KnownRouteValueConstraint` on the route. It makes it so that the route only matches if an action is found with a corresponding route value. Meaning **it will only match the route if it targets an existing area** in the case of `{area:exists}`.

You can see its source code here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/KnownRouteValueConstraint.cs.

If you do not use the exists constraint, it will work, but the point of using it is that if it receives a URL such as /SomeArea/Home/Index, it will first try the first route template. It first checks is there an action with area=SomeArea. Then it checks if it has subarea=Home. At this point it would probably figure such an action does not exist, so it rejects the match. Then it would try the next template, which would match (in a typical setup). Then of course if there is no area SomeArea, it would try the last route template. It would actually match, thinking controller=SomeArea, action=Home, id=Index. Not finding such an action = 404.

The main difference is that a URL which matches the first template will get a 404 without the constraint.

With the constraint, the template will not be selected if the URL has no matching action when used with that template.
And the framework will then try the next route template instead to locate the action.

Comment: if we do not use {area:exists} then routing will not work ?

Comment: It will work, but the point of using it is that if it receives a URL such as `/SomeArea/Home/Index`, it will first try the first route. It first checks is there an action with `area=SomeArea`. Then it checks if it has `subarea=Home`. At this point it would probably figure such an action does not exist, so it rejects the match. Then it would try the next template, which would match (in a typical setup). Then of course if there is no area SomeArea, it would try the last route template. It would actually match, thinking controller=SomeArea, action=Home, id=Index. Not finding such an action = 404.

Comment: Im still not clear on this. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @XPD I edited the answer a bit, maybe it helps? The difference is basically: without constraint, a URL /a/b/c/d matches the first template, but it could result in a 404 if no such action is actually found. The constraint ensures a matching action exists before selecting the template, and will skip it if there is no matching action.

Comment: Maybe this is to simplistic but this just seems to be another way of saying `if(exists subArea){} elseif (exists area){} else {//default}`.  Without the exists it just tries whichever route it matches and does not try any other routes. This could result in a `404` if there was a better match to the route that was not tried.

Comment: the poster's comment is confusingly explained, not easy to understand.